# Can SVG patterns overlap rather than tiling?

Tags: svg, autocad

I'm trying to migrate AutoCAD hatch patterns (*.PAT) to SVG for a web site.

These hatch patterns are [defined as](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f4875513fb5cd10c4aa30d6b-7e42.htm,topicNumber=d0e368519) a series of lines, each with a center origin, angle, delta x, and delta y, and they are repeated by incrementing the x and y by the deltas to fill the region (there are more options, but I'll leave that alone for now). For example, this pattern:

```
45, 0, 0, 0, .125
```

Produces a series of 45-degree lines starting at 0,0 and incremented by 0.125 units along the y axis:

[image]

I know that SVG supports patterns, but this is the closest I could come up with in SVG:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="Pattern" width=".2" height=".2" x="0.1" y="0.01">
        <line transform="rotate(45)" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
<rect fill="url(#Pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
```

[(Fiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbc72/)

Unfortunately, the repetition of the pattern is achieved in SVG by *tiling* (like a seamless background image) rather than by just repeating the line with offsets. This makes it impossible to have a continuous diagonal line, you can only have a series of line segments.

Is there a way to tell SVG to repeat a pattern by adding shapes to the existing canvas (overlapping each other) rather than by tiling?

My only other option seems to be creating a conversion tool that will loop and create lines until the offset origin is outside the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, patterns can't overlap, but you don't need that I think. How about using patternTransform to transform the pattern rather than transforming the lines. This looks a lot better on Firefox but I haven't tried any other UA.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <pattern patternTransform="rotate(-45)" id="Pattern" width=".2" height=".2" x="0.1" y="0.01">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:square;overflow:visible;" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="overflow:visible"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm still figuring out how to do what I need to do to offset the stroke dashes for each iteration (scaleX seems to be doing something but it's measured in degrees not the normal UOM), but overall this gave me exactly what I need.